# How Resolve Jersey Error The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-ws, java-ee-7

I have try learn Jersey and Make Rest API, I using JDK 8 for Develop this API

#### index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
    <p><a href="webapi/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
    <p>Visit <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
    for more information on Jersey!
</body>
</html>
```

#### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>LatihanJerseyCrud</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>LatihanJerseyCrud</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>LatihanJerseyCrud</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>3.0.0-M1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


</project>
```

#### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### Model

Kategori.java

```
package com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "kategori")
public class Kategori {
    @XmlElement(name = "id_Kategori")
    private int id_kat;

    @XmlElement(name="nama_kat")
    private String nama;

    public int getId_kat() {
        return id_kat;
    }

    public void setId_kat(int id_kat) {
        this.id_kat = id_kat;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public Kategori(int id_kat, String nama) {
        super();
        this.id_kat = id_kat;
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public Kategori() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


}
```

Response.java

```
package com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Response {


    @XmlElement(name = "message")
    private String message;
    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    private Boolean status;


    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public Boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Response() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Response(String message, Boolean status) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
    }


}
```

### Service

#### interface

KategoriService.java

```
package com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Service;

import com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.*;


public interface KategoriService {
    public Response addKategori(Kategori kategori);
    public Response deleteKategori(Kategori kategori);
    public Response updateKategori(Kategori kategori);
    public Kategori[] getAllKategori();

}
```

#### implements

KategoriServiceImpl.java

```
package com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.Kategori;
import com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.Response;

import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes;
import jakarta.ws.rs.DELETE;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("/kategori")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class KategoriServiceImpl implements KategoriService{

    private static Map<Integer, Kategori> mapKategori = new HashMap<Integer,Kategori>();

    @Override
    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    public Response addKategori(Kategori kategori) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Response response= new Response();
                if(mapKategori.get(kategori.getId_kat())!= null){

                    response.setStatus(false);
                    response.setMessage("Kategori is Exist!"    );
                    return response;
                }

                else {
                    mapKategori.put(kategori.getId_kat(), kategori);
                    response.setStatus(true);
                    response.setMessage("Kategori Has been Added Successfully");
                    return response;
                }
    }

    @Override
    @DELETE
    @Path("/delete")
    public Response deleteKategori(Kategori kategori) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Response response= new Response();
        if(mapKategori.get(kategori.getId_kat())==null) {
            response.setMessage("Kategori id Is not Exist!");
            response.setStatus(false);
            return response;
        }
        else {
            response.setMessage("Kategori Has Been Deleted Successfully");
            response.setStatus(true);
            mapKategori.remove(kategori.getId_kat());
            return response;

        }

    }

    @Override
    @Path("/update")
    public Response updateKategori(Kategori kategori) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Response response =new Response();
        if(mapKategori.get(kategori.getId_kat())==null) {
            response.setMessage("Kategori id Is not Exist!");
            response.setStatus(false);
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            mapKategori.put(kategori.getId_kat(), kategori);
            response.setStatus(true);
            response.setMessage("Kategori Has Been Update Successfully");
            return response;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @GET
    @Path("/getAll")
    public Kategori[] getAllKategori() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Set<Integer> ids=mapKategori.keySet();
        Kategori[] kategori= new Kategori[ids.size()];
        int i=0;
        for(Integer id:ids) {
            kategori[i]= mapKategori.get(id);
            i++;
            return kategori;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Try Hit PostMant

example:

#### Method add

**http://localhost:8080/LatihanJerseyCrud/rest/kategori/add**

> using Body raw XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kategori>
    <id_Kategori>01</id_Kategori>
    <nama_kat>Tepung</nama_kat>
</kategori>
```

**other's method's is same RESPONSE IS**

## ERROR

```
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
    <hr class="line" />
    <p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p>
    <p><b>Message</b> Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception</p>
    <p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
    </p>
    <p><b>Exception</b></p>
    <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
</pre>
    <p><b>Root Cause</b></p>
    <pre>org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] A sub-resource model, public com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.Response com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Service.KategoriServiceImpl.updateKategori(com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.Kategori), can not have an entity parameter. Try to move the parameter to the corresponding resource method.; source=&#39;ResourceMethod{httpMethod=null, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Service.KategoriServiceImpl, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@1cc0b]}, definitionMethod=public com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.Response com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Service.KategoriServiceImpl.updateKategori(com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.Kategori), parameters=[Parameter [type=class com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.Kategori, source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.Response}, nameBindings=[]}&#39;]
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:371)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:293)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$$Lambda$201&#47;31298427.call(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:292)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:311)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
</pre>
    <p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p>
    <hr class="line" />
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.54</h3>
</body>
```

I hope anyone help me for resolve this Case. Thank you!

Comment: did you add this code on github ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify the HTTP method type on **updateKategori**. Thats why the error says:

```
A sub-resource model, public com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.Response com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Service.KategoriServiceImpl.updateKategori(com.example.LatihanJerseyCrud.Model.Kategori), can not have an entity parameter. Try to move the parameter to the corresponding resource method.
```